# React redux useSelector and parameters

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-reducers

I'm trying to understand why I can't seem to pass a parameter into a selector.

In essence: I have a logic that stores a number and a bool - the number is the parameter I want to select a material element by - I have a button that dispatches an action:

```
//on a jobcard - dispatches to the material logic slice, pushing the number into the redux state: materialforJobNumber;
 <button className="materialViewer"  onClick={() =>{dispatch(materialView(data.jobsessionkey))}}> MATERIAL</button>
```

which dispatches to the logic slice:

```
//logic slice
materialView:(state, action)=>{
    console.log("what");
    console.log("material view succesfully called", action);
    const newState = {...state};
    console.log(newState);
    newState.materialforJobNumber = action.payload;
    newState.showMaterial=true;
    return newState
},
```

```
//the component that handles displaying the list of material for a job;

import {selectAttachedByJobKey} from "../MaterialCard/MaterialSlice";
const store= useStore();
const foundJN = store.getState().logic.materialforJobNumber;
const selectedJob=store.getState().jobs.find(x=>x.jobsessionkey==foundJN);
const materials = useSelector(selectAttachedByJobKey(foundJN));
const materialCards = materials.filter(x=>x.AttachedJobKey==foundJN).map((x,i)=><MaterialCard props={x} key ={i} />)
```

```
//material slice:
import { createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';

export const selectAttachedByJobKey = (state,action) =>{
    console.log("selecting material by job key",action);
    console.log(action?.payload);
    console.log(state);
    return state.material.filter(x=>x.AttachedJobkey===action?.payload);
}
```

I'm trying to get related material of a 'job' to show up on a click of a button.
I'm using the createReducer function pattern, and I'm a bit lost on how to achieve this - is there a cleaner way for using a selector with a property?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`useSelector` takes a function with only `state` as argument. if you want to pass other variables you could use a currying approach as:

```
export const selectAttachedByJobKey = (action) => (state) =>{
    console.log("selecting material by job key",action);
    console.log(action?.payload);
    console.log(state);
    return state.material.filter(x=>x.AttachedJobkey===action?.payload);
}
```

now when you do `const materials = useSelector(selectAttachedByJobKey(foundJN));` you will be passing to `useSelector` a function with `foundJN` available.

Comment: this works- and is a pattern i need to dril